# Low engine temp

Tags: engine, chevrolet, temperature, s10

2001 chevy s10 2.2 will not reach normal operating temp. First noticed when defroster was blowing cold. Replaced thermostat with Stant superstat with no change whatsoever. Coolant level is normal. Out of ideas, please help.

Comment: What does the temp gauge show?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

First Check the heater valve is working and opening to allow the hot coolant through.

Second check to see if the heater matrix (a small radiator) is blocked.

Either of these could be the cause or even a blocked pipe.
It could also be a failing or failed water pump, but it should have shown signs of overheating...

I have assumed that the new thermostst is functioning correctly - perhaps testing it would be a good idea...

Comment: the temperature gauge indicates midway between 100 and 210, approximately 160F. I am considering having the radiator shop flush out the dexcool and replacing it with the green stuff. I did not test the new stat.

Comment: What is the temperature specifications of the new thermostat? If too low, the whole cooling system may be held at a too-low temperature.

Comment: @David “what are...”

Comment: @SolarMike Is my comment unclear? Thermostats (at least in the old days...) used to come in several temperatures. Here, the OP would want to determine that a) the thermo has the right specs, and b) that it's opening at the right temperature, and not at a lower temperature than expected.

Comment: @David what are the temperature specifications or what is the temperature specification... usually a range though and they are not very precise in my experience. Best electric fan control I ever had was when i used a cylinder stat (from a hot water tank) on the bottom hose...

Comment: @SolarMike As far as I remember, the spec was indeed singular. I don't know if that's the "begin to open" or "fully open" temp. If the engine's colder than it should be, we know the cooling system is cooling OK, but the low-temp result could be because the thermostat's controlling it to that low temp.

Comment: @David you expect the common garden wax stat to open at 82 degrees c precisely... really...

Comment: No, I don't. That kind of accuracy isn't achievable at auto-store prices. But an 82 degree 'stat is apt to open earlier than an 86 degree one, and later than a 78 degree one. We don't know what the OP has. All I'm advocating is that the OP look at it and see. It wouldn't be the first time the wrong part was supplied and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you mentioned Dexcool in your comment to solar Mike's answer. There is a known issue with Dexcool turning to a kind of sludge or mud after many years of use in a cooling system.  This could easily clogged up something like a radiator core.  Just do a Google search for Dexcool sludge or Dexcool mud.  You may want to check your cooling system to see if it needs to be flushed here is a good Guide to the subject :

http://www.sancarlosradiator.com/VoltageDrop/flush.htm

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts of that article, in case it goes down, so we have the resource here still too?

Answer (score 0):

Is the fan constantly running? This is the main thought that would account for your issue based on it running fine otherwise. Your thermostat retains the coolant back until the radiator has removed enough heat to match the set temp of the thermostat. I early on thought the Thermostat was purely designed to open the cooling system to the radiator once the engine coolant temp reached 185/ 195/ 205 etc. But when in college my instructor explained the true working of the system. If an engine flowed freely without thermostats on a long drive the engine would run far too cold causing the engine to run less than efficiently. One point here on your car heating system. The heater uses a bypass system to push and circulate the coolant to the heater core inside the car via the aprx. 5/8-inch hoses connected forward of the thermostat and water pump regions. Lack of heat to the heater core may be lack of flow past the heater control valve (closed/ frozen) and no coolant is reaching the heater core inside your car. I have replaced many heater control valves over my career.